# PHP file organization

Tags: php

I am just getting started with PHP (I do have experience with html css and javascript). I want to create a form on my websites contact page. The user can fill out the form, the fields will be check for things like null etc.

My problem is I have this in a file called contact.html, and I have the script in a email.php file. I am not sure how to run the email.php without the white screen that the page opens. Ideally The user would click the "submit" button, the form would be check for errors then I want to email it (php mail() function).

What would be the top ways to go about this. Everything in one contact.php file or Call php from javascript?

Answer (score 0):

You can include the email.php file

```
include "email.php";
```

In the email.php, check to make sure the form has been submitted, by checking the value of the button.

```
if(isset($_POST['my-form-button'])){
   //user has submitted the form
}
```

The include should be at the very top of your contact page.

Comment: Thanks! So if I include the email.php page, how would I run the php code?

Comment: It is run automatically when the original file is run.

Comment: `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') { ... }` is the 100% reliable method for checking the POST state. Anything else is subject to failure due to programmer error.